# Error: file size Pdf

Tags: php, filesize

I know the size of my file every time I have the same error

this is my code :

```
$file_path = '/home/toufik.medhaffar/Téléchargements/Resume-Toufik-MEDHAFFAR.pdf';
        $size = filesize ($file_path);
        $save_path = $file_path;
```

this is the error :

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /home/toufik.medhaffar/Téléchargements/Resume-Toufik-MEDHAFFAR.pdf"
}
```

any idea??

Comment: Most likely php is configured not to grant access to files outside the http servers document root.

Comment: This error is generally created when u try to access the files outside your document root directory.